# Android Studio - Java - Attaching an ImageView to a Layout defined in a XML file

Tags: android, layout, imageview, parent

My code is the following:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ImageView (android.content.Context) in ImageView cannot be applied to (int)
```

I guess somehow my Layout wants to return an integer value, I just want to set my ImageView to my Layout, thank you for the help!

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT 2:

I have my layout set to be displayed and I can see it when running the application, I made the background greenish so I'm sure in that:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
```

Here is the .xml file:

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#162216"
    tools:context=".main.MainMenuActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

I have my Layout defined, my ImageView defined, the question is how to pair them together so that the ImageView becomes part of the Layout, so it can be displayed as a picture?

While my Layout is defined in an .xml file, my ImageView is written directly into my .java class

Comment: have you checked what are the parameters of ImageView constructor? What do yhou want to do with it?

Comment: @Hydraxia 
Please check constructor parameter should your layout file contains only imageview?

Comment: R.layout.activity_main_menu is an integer value defined in R.java class. But new ImageView(context); take a context(context of activity) as parameter in constructor.

Comment: It says that the ImageView can be constructed using only a "Context" from API 21, I figured if I simply put my Layout there it would work, I cannot imagine anything else to put there

Comment: @SanjayKumar Thank you, yes I want to do exactly that, a Layout should be considered a context of an Activity, is that right? I don't know why it's not working

Comment: define ImageView in your MainLayout (say relative layout). Than you can fetch it as ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.myImage);

Comment: I would like to know how to fetch the layout when it's defined in an .xml file while the ImageView is not, sorry I know it would be easier to define them both in an .xml file but I'm planning on having lots of ImageViews later on dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

even though this solution is WRONG and don't do it like that.

**xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#162216"
    tools:context=".main.MainMenuActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

**code:**

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageResource);
frameLayout.addView(imageView);
```

if you want to have a lot of images for later, you will need to have them in a recycler view most propably, there is chance that you will not need to recycler them so you will go with the solution to add them in a LinearLayout.

note: FrameLayout can have only 1 child

Answer (score 0):

Set R.layout.activity_main_menu) in your onCreate method Like this :

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

Then set your imageView ID from xml

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you, you mean the constructor for my ImageView should be itself? I want it to be attached to a Layout if you know what I mean